# Linq and conditional sum

Tags: linq

I have a class and a list as below:

```
class C1
{
    int RecType ...;
    decimal Income ...;
    decimal Outcome ...;
}

List<C1> myList ...;
```

The list is loaded with several records, and they have various values in RecType
What I want is to calculate total on Income and Outcome but only for a certain value of RecType

Here's a pseudo code of what I need to get

```
totalIncome = myList.Sum(Income).Where(RecType==1);
```

How can I accomplish this with linq?

Thank you

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
totalIncome = myList.Where(x => x.RecType == 1).Select(x => x.Income).Sum();
```

First you filter on the record type (`Where`); then you transform by `Select`ing the `Income` of each object; and finally you `Sum` it all up.

Or for a slightly more terse version:

```
totalIncome = myList.Where(x => x.RecType == 1).Sum(x => x.Income);
```

Answer (score 42):

```
totalIncome = myList.Sum(c=>
    (c.RecType==1 ? c.Income : 0));
```

Comment: Thanks alot, this seemed to be the only fix for me to get the sum of a nullable decimal.

Comment: This is awesome! Works with linq to entities and even solves the problem for when the list is empty.